# Function to replace tab targetting enemies in MMO games

Tags: automation, logic, autohotkey, mmo

I'm struggling a bit to think of a way to design a good function which will generically target enemies in an MMO if they do not support tab targeting.

So my thoughts are this currently:

```
targetEnemy(hpBar,area) {
   Click randomly in screen 'area' (avoid UI elements) until 'hpBar' appears
}
```

Is there a better way? My concerns:
 1. Accounting for the end of the map/edges/location transfers
 2. Getting into aggro range of enemies but not clicking them during the Rng clicking, causing myself to take damage and waste healing sources.
 3. Looking like a botter by spazzing around the map

Comment: If you run your game in some sort of windowed mode you might be able to do it with pixelsearch/imagesearch. But it would take a lot of time to get this figured out for your game.  A cleaner and more reliable solution would be to hack into the memory area of the game using processreadmemory and the like. That requires knowledge about tools like ollydbg or cheat engine though.

Comment: As you are probably the 1000s person to ask about this, you should read through the threads of those who already managed to do this.